# Losing connection to server at every reboot (18.04 LTS)

Tags: networking

I'm quite new to Linux in general. And did some "rookie" mistakes...

I tried to install Pi-Hole on my server, and did also install lighttpd (by mistake, I forgot that Apache2 was running).

Now, Pi-Hole web interface somehow does not work, so I attempted a reboot. Which made me lose connection to the server, and thereby SSH won't work anymore...

I'm using `bond0` with 2 assigned Ethernets.

The `eth1` assigns itself with an IP on every startup, `bond0` usually use the assigned static IP (which is supposed to be). `eth2` doesn't display any IP address.

Whenever I do run

```
sudo netplan apply
```

The server gains connectivity, but

```
sudo apt update
```

still doesn't seem to work. But the `eth1` loses its static IP.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out.

"dhcpcd" was also installed, besides Pi-Hole. Which is why eth1 was assigned an IP

I ran these commands:

sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd.service

and

sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd.service

(Sorry, I don't know how to make headers/blocks!)